# Ho do I set the zoom level on a simple map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zooming

There are many questions on setting the zoom level, but I can't find an answer to this simple question here. I'm new to this stuff and eager to learn :)
I have a simple map initiated in a div (Windows Chrome).

The original zoom level is 8 and I can zoom the map in and out using the scroll wheel.
I have disabled the key board short cuts for man and zoom, but want to the use + and - keys to grammatically zoom in and out. I'm using the javascript API v3.

When the user presses the +/- I calculate a new zoom level and call map.setZoom()

```
function zoomMap(e){
switch(e.keyCode){
    case PLUS : zoomLevel+=0.1;
        break;
    case MINUS: zoomLevel-=0.1;
        break;
}
map.setZoom(zoomLevel);
```

}

The debugger shows that the new level is correct, and the map is known within the function (in scope)

The map is updated, but shows the new view only for a brief moment, then it disappears. The canvas goes grey, and the console log says error 400 (Bad request).

Trying

```
    map.setOptions({zoom:zoomLevel});
```

gives same result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: Darn! I knew it had to be simple. This is the usual annoyance. You have a problem. You know it must have a simple solution, and you search high and low for an answer. Finally you cry for help, and as soon as you do, you find the answer in some random unrelated posting.

**Zoom levels are integers only**

So many hours for a simple unknown ;)
Thanks for reading!